# How to get past factory-reset home screen (Hello) without a home button on iPhone 6+?

Tags: iphone

My stepdad recently ran into some issues with his iPhone, and I'm trying to fix it.

From what I understand, the home button is broken and he factory reset it and took out the sim card (as he got a new phone). The issue is that I can get it to the white Hello screen, but it wants you to press the home button to continue - and I can't.

So I connected it to iTunes to try to bypass it, however it can't actually connect to iTunes as I get the message:

"iTunes could not connect to the iPhone “iPhone” because it is locked with a passcode. You must enter your passcode on the iPhone before it can be used with iTunes."

But, I can't enter the passcode, as I can't get past the Hello screen.

Any ideas here? Thanks